# WKWebView in Cocoa app can't get the cursor on click

Tags: cocoa, wkwebview, appkit, nstextfield, nsresponder

I created a simple test app where one field is an `NSTextField` and another is a `<textarea>` instead a `WKWebView`. I can click into the web view once, but if I go back to the `NSTextField`, I'm unable to get the cursor back into the web view ever again.

Here's a demonstration:

[image]

As you can see, the web view is still interactive to some extent, it just can't become (I assume) the first responder again.

Is there something weird about `WKWebView` and the responder chain? How can I make the `WebWebView` behave like a normal `NSTextField`?

[Here is a sample project](https://d.pr/f/IaCwEI) built in Xcode 11.5 in case you want to try it out.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the *textarea*, using [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) `<body contenteditable="true"></body>` does seem to work.

A workaround for using the *textarea* is to subclass *WKWebView* like this:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [super mouseDown:event];
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
}
```

Comment: Setting the `contenteditable` attribute on the `body` didn't work for me (the 2nd click on the web view is still ignored) but the `WKWebView` subclass seems to work great. Thank you!